# Sharing documents via intent/Fileprovider

Tags: android, pdf, whatsapp, sharing, android-fileprovider

Problem 1: I have a pdf stored in

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() --> /storage/emulated/0/appname/downloads/sample.pdf
```

I'm sending it using normal way as shown:

```
File iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final String selpath = iconsStoragePath.getAbsolutePath() + "/appname/downloads/";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(selpath + "/" + item.getFilename());
String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
intent.setType(mimeType);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"));
```

Now the result is

[image]

The problem is file is sharing without the filename.

Problem 2: When I'm trying to use the file provider the pdf is not sharing gives me an error:

> Unable to share. Please try again

```
Environment.getFilesDir() --> /data/data/com.myapp.name/files/myapp/downloads/sample.pdf
```

Manifest File:

```
<application>
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/nnf_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

xml/nnf_provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files-path
    name="root"
    path="myapp/downloads" />
```

Code:

```
File path = new File(getFilesDir(), "downloads");
File file = new File(documentsPath + "/" + filename);
                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Which is the better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally prefer #2. Read [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b) article on how to use `ShareCompat` to create `ShareIntents`

Regarding your problem with approach #2, I guess you're missing `.setData` or `.setDataAndUri`:

This is a sample snippet which works for me for sharing images via `FileProviders`:

```
public static void shareImage(Activity context) {

    Log.d(TAG, "initializing share image");
    File imgPath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DEFAULT_TEMP_DIR_NAME);
    File newFile = new File(imgPath, DEFAULT_TEMP_FILENAME);
    String authority = context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
    Log.d(TAG, "authority: " + authority);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, newFile);

    if (contentUri != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(context)
                .setType("image/png")
                .setStream(contentUri)
                .setSubject(context.getString(R.string.share_subject))
                .setText(context.getString(R.string.share_message))
                .setEmailTo(new String[]{"example@example.com"})
                .getIntent();
        shareIntent.setData(contentUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                shareIntent, context.getString(R.string.share_chooser_title)));
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do this for multiple files ???